# JWT validation in rails requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, jwt, rails-engines

I have authentication service using

> Json Web Token

in my Rails API.
I want to check if Token is valid in every request my API gets.

Problem is that when i write function which checks if Token is valid in main

> application_controller.rb

file it is not visible in engines and i can't do before_action for every engine i have. is there any way to validate Token  in every request my application gets in every engine?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.rb` file under `config/initializers`

```
class ActionController::Base
  before_action :validate_jwt_token

  def validate_jwt_token
    # validate jwt token
  end
end
```

This will make sure `validate_jwt_token` is executed on every request among all of the mounted engines.

Edit:

You can also put this code under Api engine or Umg's `engine.rb`

```
module Api
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    #...

    initializer 'api.jwt_token_validation_helper' do
      ActionController::Base.send :include, Api::JwtTokenValidationHelper
    end
  end
end

module Api
  module JwtTokenValidationHelper
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include do
      before_action :validate_jwt_token

      def validate_jwt_token
        puts 'your code here'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have on more question, I have two engine, Api and Umg, Umg is mounted to Api and where should i put action_controller.rb file, inside api engine's config fodler or outside in main config folder?

Comment: @ditojanelidze it should be under your main app's config folder, although I believe that you can also put it under any mounted engine with a little change. I will update my answer